# What do you name your Entity Framework data model?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

With your LINQ or Entity Framework data models... what do you use as a standard naming convention for your data models? Or do you even have a standard? Using Northwind as the example...

NorthwindDB?
NorthwindData?
NWDB?

Comment: Do you mean the data model that the rest of the application will use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually go with the most general description, often the app name.  So, if it's a travel application, I might call it TravelApplication.edmx.  Your ObjectContext will then be `TravelApplicationEntities`, which I think makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

We have several Entity Models in each project to improve maintainability and managability, normally one model for each subsystem.

We then name the models according to the subsystem they belong to. For example for a insurance system you may have:

- ClaimsEntities
- ProductEntities
- PolicyEntities

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean in c#, I'd go with

```
Northwind.Data
```

in SQL, I wouldn't care.